# Checking which textview is clicked android

Tags: android, textview

I want to put two textviews and then decide which one of them is clicked to start the appropriate activity? I don't want to use buttons. Any idea??

Comment: Did you try to google a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code in `onCreate`

```
TextView texVar= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box_Name);
TextView texVar2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box_Name2);

texVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     //code here ...
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked first!!", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

  texVar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     //code here ...
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked second!!", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't work too, only one of the textviews is detected

Comment: It worked, I instead of working with view I was put TextView.OnTouchListener() , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just imlements the View.onClickListener interface in your activity, add:

```
textView1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

To each textView in your activity. Inside the onClick(View v) implementation add:

```
v.getId();
```

To determine whice TextView pressed.

Comment: Didn't work is not very clear. It should work. You get Exceptions? so bring your logs to see what you did wrong.

Comment: It din't crash, its just the activity that didn't react

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
TextView name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box_Name);
TextView name2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box_Name2);

name.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTouch(View v) {

     //code here ...
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked first...", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

  name2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTouch(View v) {

     //code here ...
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked second..", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```